# pg_dump not returning file with contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I am trying to use my docker setup to have a backup script of my databases run on a schedule, but I am having an issue setting up my code even on dev as there are no output errors, just my dumped file is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the script to backup the DB

```
def run_command(backup_command):
    import subprocess
    output = subprocess.check_output(f"{backup_command}", shell=True)

@shared_task
def backup_all_databases():
    """
    Used to backup databases to cloud storage
    
    """

    final_storage_locations = list()
    latest_storage_locations = list()

    for db_name, db_values in settings.DATABASES.items():
        # conn data...
        user = db_values["USER"]
        password = db_values["PASSWORD"]
        host =db_values["HOST"]
        port=db_values["PORT"]
        # connection_string = f'psql postgres://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}'
        # run_command(connection_string + ' --list')
        location_on_server = f'/mnt/client_database_backups/{db_name}/'
        if not os.path.exists(location_on_server):
            os.makedirs(location_on_server)
        # normal
        final_storage_location = f'{location_on_server}{db_name}_{slugify(timezone.now())}.sqlc'
        final_storage_locations.append(final_storage_location)
        # latest
        latest_name_storage_location = f'{location_on_server}latest.sqlc'
        latest_storage_locations.append(latest_name_storage_location)

        # store this for easy access
        backup_command = f'PGPASSWORD="{password}" pg_dump --format=c --compress=9 -h {host} -U {user} {db_name} -p {port}' \
                         f' >{final_storage_location}'

        latest_backup_command = f'PGPASSWORD="{password}" pg_dump --format=c --compress=9 -h {host} -U {user} {db_name} -p {port}' \
                         f' >{latest_name_storage_location}'

        # run_command(backup_command)
        run_command(latest_backup_command)
        print(latest_backup_command)
```

The backup command being run on dev is:

`PGPASSWORD="postgres" pg_dump --format=c --compress=9 -h postgres -U postgres client -p 5432 >/mnt/client_database_backups/client/latest.sqlc`

Comment: Run an intentionally defective command and make sure it generates the output you think it should, and it goes where you think it should go.

Comment: @jjanes I do not understand your statement. I am able to run this command with my production DB credentials and it works. This is an error only happening locally within my docker services

Comment: So you have two bugs on dev.  Why is it not working?  Why is it not reporting that it is not working (or at least, why aren't you seeing those reports)?  I'm suggesting you tackle it starting with the 2nd of those bugs.

Comment: I did get this working production-wise which is what I needed but I'm still unsure why it doesn't work on dev. I don't even know what to lookup why there are no errors for an empty dump of a full DB, or nothing is showing for it...but I think the issue could be that postgres is running in a different service than the 'web' service I am running the backup from with pg_dump. 'web' depends on 'postgres' in docker-compose and they are used together in the system so communication should not be an issue